# Why city name missing for some locations from Google Maps API result?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

When I enter the location details in the google API developer page, the city name is missing from the results.

The Location details are "Canarsie, Brooklyn, NY, United States".

I entered the details in the form appearing in the following link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

But city name is missing from it. This doesn't happen for all the locations. It only happens for some locations. Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was because of it stopped sending CITY under LOCALITY type but just one from **sublocality_level_1, sublocality, political** types.

I notice now, that city is working under LOCALITY only when you fill name of city to search input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

Address component type for "city" varies across regions, specially in New York.

For more details, see paragraph right under the form, in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform